# How to move the scrollbar away from the right border of a component

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar, overflow

In an application I display data in table form.

The main columns are grouped in the red frame representing the parent component. I want to add an additional summary column on the right outside the scrollable area.

what I tried is to play with the `overflow-x:visible`, but it doesn't work as explained here :
https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

How can I handle this with a pure html/css solution ?

[image]

```css
.parent {
  border:2px red solid;
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:visible;
  width:500px;
}

.child {
  background:green;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  width:600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to remove your width or add another table to the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a suitable solution for my scrollbar problem.

the following modifications are necessary:

- the `width` of the parent must be equal to that of the child
- the `overflow-y` of the parent must be set to `overlay`.
- specify a `width` of the scrollbar of `200px`.
- use the scrollbar customization to have a thinner track & thumb than the scrollbar using a large `border-right: 190px` and the `background-clip: content-box`.

I think it can still be optimized

[image]

```css
.parent {
  border:2px red solid;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:overlay;
  width:600px;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 200px;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background:yellow;
    background-clip: content-box;
    border-right: 190px solid transparent;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.parent:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color:blue;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-right: 190px solid transparent;
}

.child {
  display:table-row;
  font-size:20px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding-top:10px;
  width:600px;
}

.column--1,
.column--2 {
  background:#C4FFCE;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:150px;
}

.column--1 {
  width:435px;
}

.space {
  width:55px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>  
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="column--1">column 1</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="column--2">column 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  border:2px red solid;
  height:400px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:visible;
  width:500px;
}

.child {
  background:green;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  width:600px;
}
.p1{
  display:flex;
  
  width:500px;
    
}
.p2{
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="p1">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
  <div class="p2">
  ggg
  </div>
  
  </div>
```

i am giving sample . you do like this

Comment: it doesn't work as expected, when I use the blue scrollbar, the green lines (also on the right of the scrollbar) should move accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have it so that the scrollbar isn't on the right edge, at least not just with HTML and CSS. Here is the closest I could get

```css
body {margin: 0} * {box-sizing: border-box} /* IGNORE */

.parent {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  background: rgba(0,180,60, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0,180,60);
  margin:5px;
  
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - (5px * 2)); /* Account for margin */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display data in one column, lists, either `<ul>` or `<ol>` are ususally the semantically correct choice. To display data in more than one column, as it's the case here, you need a `<table>`.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first col</td>
    <td>second col</td>
  </tr>
...
</table>
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
tr > td {
  width: 100vw
}
```